# Custom E-mail headers, ensure trustworthy source

Tags: email

There may well be a better solution to this problem, and I welcome those as well.

At the moment, I have an e-mail form on my website where people can send an e-mail directly to my gmail account through a PHP script. However, when I receive those e-mails, sometimes gmail flags it as possibly spam or phishing; presumably because the e-mail didn't come from a known server.

I was just wondering if there was anyway to tell gmail that if it comes from my server, it is safe. I thought that maybe I could add a unique custom header and tell gmail that that means it's a safe source?

I'm not very familiar with the deeper complexities of e-mail and e-mail servers, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You could start by creating the appropriate SPF record in your DNS zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure your application code to use a SMTP relay service, rather than sending the emails yourself.

Sendgrid springs to mind, as a possible alternative, but there are many alternative SMTP as a Service solutions.

As you're using Amazon EC2 already, it's definitely worth investigating [Amazon Simple Email Service](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/pricing/) (SES) which has a very generous free tier allowance.

Comment: Are there any free alternatives to Sendgrid? This is just a personal, non-commercial website  for use as an online CV/Resume.

Comment: I googled for 'free SMTP relay' and found a whole bunch with free tiers.  There's also a free tier on [Amazon Simple Email Service](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/pricing/)...

Comment: You can use your own Gmail account as a relay.  Just setup an application specific password, and use the settings they give you.

Comment: You can, but they have hard sending limits, which aren't that high.

Comment: It looks like Amazon SES is perfect for me, as I am already using an EC2 instance to host the site anyway.. the first GB of e-mails per month costs nothing, and there is absolutely no way I would expect to get that many. So, I will accept this as the answer. Thanks!